# refactoring common pattern in shared concerns

Tags: ruby-on-rails

An application has controller action methods with repeating patterns.
Essentially, on a toggle items are added or removed, a counter amended and a toggle state changed.  The methods are within a shared concern.
*note these may not necessarily be referring to objects of the same class*
This is one such method:

```
def toggle_territory_criteria
  if params[:criteria] == "none" 
    if params[:toggle].to_i == 0
      @region_none_active = 0
      @regional_total = params[:regional_total].to_i - params[:value].to_i
    else
      @region_none_active = 1
      @regional_total = params[:regional_total].to_i + params[:value].to_i
    end
  else
    if params[:toggle].to_i == 0
      @active_regionminor_ids.delete(params[:criteria].to_i)
      @regional_total = params[:regional_total].to_i - params[:value].to_i
    else
      @active_regionminor_ids = params[:regionminors] << params[:criteria].to_i
      @regional_total = params[:regional_total].to_i + params[:value].to_i
    end
  end
end
```

This can be refactored and fully abstracted in the following three methods:

```
def toggle_state(attribute)
  attribute = false
  if params[:toggle].to_i == 0
    attribute = true
  end
end

def toggle_collection(id_collection, criteria_attribute)
  id_collection << criteria_attribute
  if params[:toggle].to_i == 0
    id_collection.delete(criteria_attribute)
  end
end

def toggle_sums(sum_value, original_sum, new_value)
  sum_value = original_sum + new_value
  if params[:toggle].to_i == 0
    sum_value = original_sum - new_value
  end
end
```

leading to a succinct concern method

```
def toggle_territory_criteria_too
  if params[:criteria] == "none"
    toggle_state(@region_none_active)
    toggle_sums(@regional_total, params[:regional_total].to_i, params[:value].to_i)
  else
    toggle_collection(@active_regionminor_ids, params[:criteria].to_i)
    toggle_sums(@regional_total, params[:regional_total].to_i, params[:value].to_i)
  end
end
```

However, the resulting variables are not accessible in the originating method nor in the views (the concern method was using instance variables for this purpose).

What would be a proper way to execute this refactoring to service the controller action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ruby (and thus Rails, of course), a method never changes the values of the objects it receives as arguments, except when *destructive* methods are used.

In your case, when you run `toggle_state(@region_none_active)`, the method `toggle_state` never changes `@region_none_active`, for example. What `toggle_state` does is only to return the value of the last executed line, namely either the value of `if params[:toggle].to_i == 0` if it is false or the returned value of the line of `attribute = true`, which is `true`. `attribute` in the method `toggle_state` is a local variable and changing it has nothing to do with `@region_none_active`.

Similarly, the method `toggle_sums` **never changes anything** and simply returns either Numeric or `false`(!), depending on a set of the given value as the attributes. I am sure you would not want the value `false` from the method!

Instead, the following would set the instance variable (at the caller's side), for example, of `@region_none_active` in your concern method.

```rb
  @region_none_active = toggle_state(@region_none_active)
```

You need similar modifications for the other methods in your code.  This specification is Ruby's fundamental principle, and so consult the Ruby reference or textbook for detail (but I am sure you know that?).

Anf finally, if you want to access the instance variable `@region_none_active` from your view, you probably would need to write your own getter method for it, like

```rb
  # Your model
  attr_reader :region_none_active
  # And access it from your model "mdl" like
  #   mdl.region_none_active
```

where `attr_reader` is a Ruby built-in alias of
`def region_none_active; @region_none_active; end`

---

Note I would recommend to rewrite your `toggle_state` as follows for the sake of clarity, though what it does is identical to your code (and to add, a better name for the method would be something like `desired_state?` according to Ruby's convention for method names):

```rb
def toggle_state(attribute)
  params[:toggle].to_i == 0
end
```

Another note is, the two methods `id_collection <<` and `id_collection.delete` in your code are destructive and hence modify the caller's object. So you need to handle them with care. To be honest, I would not recommend to use such destructive methods in a method because to change the caller's object directly in a user method would usually make your code less organised and hard to read.  I'd stick to non-destructive methods only in general.